# calling class_respondsToSelector for a Swift class method from Objective-C code

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a Swift class as below

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    func helloWorld(a: String)
    {
        print(a);
    }
}
```

Assuming my target name is `Pebble`, from an objective-c class, I need to find out, if the class `ViewController` responds to selector `helloWorld:`. I have tried the following statements:

```
class_respondsToSelector(NSClassFromString(@"Pebble.ViewController"), NSSelectorFromString(@"helloWorld"))
class_respondsToSelector(NSClassFromString(@"Pebble.ViewController"), NSSelectorFromString(@"helloWorld:"))
class_respondsToSelector(NSClassFromString(@"ViewController"), NSSelectorFromString(@"helloWorld:"));
class_respondsToSelector(NSClassFromString(@"ViewController"), NSSelectorFromString(@"helloWorld"));
```

However,

1) In `ViewController` when I write `let responds = self.responds(to: Selector("helloWorld:"))` - it returns `true`.

2) In `AppDelegete` when I write `let responds = ViewController.responds(to: Selector("helloWorld:"))` - it returns `false`.

3) In `AppDelegete` when I write `let responds = ViewController.instancesRespond(to: Selector("helloWorld:"))` - it returns `false`.

All of the above returns `NO`. What should be done to fix this or what is the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
class_respondsToSelector(NSClassFromString(@"{YOUR_MODULE_PRODUCT_NAME}.ViewController"), NSSelectorFromString(@"helloWorldWithA:"))
```

In Swift 3, the first argument label is a part of method signature and when generating Objective-C selector it is concatenated with "With", so, the default Objective-C selector for `func helloWorld(a: String)` becomes `helloWorldWithA:`.

If you do not like this behaviour, you can write your `helloWorld` as `func helloWorld(_ a: String)`, and its Objective-C selector becomes `helloWorld:`.

Or you can specify Objective-C selector explicitly with `@objc` annotation.
Writing like `@objc(helloWorld:) func helloWorld(a: String)`, the Objective-C selector for it becomes `helloWorld:` as specified.

Comment: this works. How would the ObjC equivalent would look when function is like `helloWorld(a: String b: String)` (i.e. multiple params). Is the behaviour different in Swift 2.3?

Comment: "when generating Objective-C selector it is concatenated with "With"" - interesting!

Comment: @prabodhprakash, It becomes `helloWorldWithA:b:`, Objective-C selector having two arguments has two colons.

Comment: And the behaviour in Swift 2.3, is it the same?

Comment: @prabodhprakash, I cannot test with 2.3, but it would be `helloWorld:b:` in Swift 2.3. In Swift 2, the first parameter's label is ignored by default.

Comment: Okay, I will test this out. Many thanks for quick help :-)

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions I can think of:

- Annotate your class, `@objc(ViewController), to make sure it is exposed with the right name
- Qualify your selector with the parameter name, i.e. `helloWorld(a:)`